Questions about PL2303 UART and RS232
I’ve had a great experience connecting an NFC reader to my laptop using a PL2303TA cable. It converts the USB to UART TTL, and it’s super effective when you have a driver like libnfc to do the heavy lifting, but I also want to experiment with an old RS232 serial peripheral I have and I’m sensing some confusion about the cable on cheap electronics websites.
If you shop around in the usual places you’ll find cables marked “PL2303 USB/UART/Serial” but having researched a bit, I’m pretty sure these are not RS232, because that would require voltages between 3 to 15V and -3 to -15V, whereas I’m pretty sure the cable containing the PL2303 is UART TTL, being 0 to 5 V (Or 0 to 3.3V if you re solder the chip inside the little case.)
Also I looked up the datasheet, and it says that to make the PL2303 into an USB to RS232 you have to add an SP213EHCA, but other more casual sources say that it might work if you can invert the bits in software.
If someone could shed some light on why Ali and other sources call this RS232 and if I’m missing something, or are they just wrong?
Also for bonus points, if I resolder the cable from 5V down to 3.3, does it change both the VCC and the TTL signal levels? I’m guessing yes.

The sellers just don't understand what they are selling and label it wrong.
RS-232, while still relevant being over 80 year old standard, isn't so common anymore that everyone these days would understand what it means - after all it was deprecated from PCs about 25 years ago in 1998 by the PC97 specification made by Microsoft and Intel, so many people studying electronics are more familiar with USB than RS-232 serial ports.
So the PL2302 UART chip has a TTL interface and can be used to make an RS-232 serial interface by attaching a RS-232 transceiver chip to it - just like you make a RS-485 interface by attaching a RS-485 transceiver chip to it.
Some sensors have implement RS-232 compatible output by using 5V TTL levels and inverting the level - a typical RS-232 serial port should generally accept the signal.
The other way is not so simple - your input would need to tolerate RS-232 levels and invert the data for giving 5V TTL signal to your USB UART.
If you want to play around with real RS-232 devices, buy a ready made USB-RS232 cable, or do it yourself by attaching a RS-232 transceiver to your USB-TTL cable.
